# Setting Width on DatePicker or TimePicker XAML UAP

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible. It seems like the min width is fixed and you can't set the width for lets say the month column. You get a month cell that's really large if you use integer (2)

Google didn't help hope this will :-)

```
<DatePicker
        YearVisible="False"
        DayFormat="{}{day.integer(2)}"
        MonthFormat="{}{month.integer(2)}"
        Grid.Row="1" 
        >
```

Answer (score 2):

You can open your project in blend, then right click on the DatePicker in your Objects window and choose Edit Template -> Edit a copy.

After you click ok the style will be pasted in your XAML. Go down until you reach the ContentPresenter control, in there you will find a grid with column definitions.

It should look something like this

```
....
<ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,8" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
    <Button x:Name="FlyoutButton" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}" Style="{StaticResource DatePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}">
        <Grid x:Name="FlyoutButtonContentGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DayColumn" Width="78*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="FirstSpacerColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MonthColumn" Width="132*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="SecondSpacerColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="YearColumn" Width="78*"/>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 ....
```

Alter the columns as you desire

Answer (score 1):

This introduced me to using Blend, which I had for unknown reasons, previously avoided.  I note that after altering the ColumnDefinition as desired, one should also look a the "MinWidth" and "MaxWidth" Setter properties to see if they need to be changed to allow the widths you are setting.